# What angle is $\sin^{-1}(3/2)$?

Tags: trigonometry

So i have this trigonometric equations: $$2\cos^2(x)+4\sin(x)+\cos(2x)=0$$

I have rewritten the expression and came up with $$(2\sin(x)-3)(1+2\sin(x))=0$$

Then i split the equation in two and got

$$\sin(x)=3/2,\quad\text{and}\quad\sin(x)=-1/2$$

Since $\sin(x)=-1/2$ is a standard angle and with respect to the period I got $x=\pi - \sin^{-1}(11\pi/6)$

The problem is that I can not figure out what angle $\sin(x)=(3/2)$.

I have tried using the Pythagorean theorem but since $\sin$ is $\text{opp}/\text{hyp}$, it tells me that something is wrong since the hypotenuse can not be shorter than the sides.

Does anyone have an idea of what I should do?

Comment: For real $x$ you have $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$.  As you say, the hypotenuse can not be shorter than the sides.

Comment: You need to define your domain first

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You can learn to typeset your math with LaTeX or Mathjax. You got some help on this question by us but it is good to learn for the future as it increases chance of getting answers.

Comment: 1) sin x <= 1 so sin x = 3/2 is impossible  2)"so I split and got sin x = 3/ *and* sin x = -1/2".  No!!!!  You split and you got sin x = 3/ **OR** sin x = -1/2
 They can't *BOTH* be true because $3/2 \ne -1/2$ so sin x can't equal *both* of them at the same time.  So one **OR** the other is true.  And as sin x = 3/2 is utterly impossible, it must be that sin x = -1/2 is the one that is true.

Comment: @fleablood "utterly impossible"? You do realise $sin z = 3/2$ has solutions for complex $z$?

Comment: We aren't talking complex.  It's utterly impossible in the reals.

Comment: THe point being $f(x)*g(x) = 0$.  $f(x) = 0$ being unsolvable is *not* a problem, as $f(x) \ne 0$ is always a possibility.  Now *if* f(x) is unsolvable that means $g(x)$ *must* equal 0.  ... But $f(x) \ne 0$ is NOT a problem.

Comment: @mathreadler i will look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $\sin(x) = \frac{3}{2}$ has no solution because $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.
So you can just solve $\sin(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Extending to complex plane,
$$\sin^{-1} \frac{3}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-2i\ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)$$

This can be easily verified by using

$$\sin (x+yi) = \sin x \cosh y+i\cos x \sinh y$$

Comment: It is trigonometry of precalculus, so we have not been in touch with the complex plane.

Comment: The number of solutions to the equation depends on the domain of the variables. Your domain is the real numbers, so the complex-number solution does not apply. You have correctly concluded that the only solution is $-1/2$. Someone who encounters an equation like this in a complex analysis course, however, might want to consider this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$\sin(x)=\frac{3}{2}$$
for $x$.

Rewrite the sine function in terms of exponential function:
$$\frac{3}{2}=\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i};$$
multiply both sides by $2i$:
$$3i=e^{ix}-e^{-ix};$$
subtract $3i$ from both sides:
$$e^{ix}-3i-e^{-ix}=0;$$
multiply both sides by $e^{ix}$:
$$\left(e^{ix}\right)^2-3ie^{ix}-e^{-ix}e^{ix}=0;$$
rewrite $e^{-ix}e^{ix}=1$:
$$\left(e^{ix}\right)^2-3ie^{ix}-1=0;$$
substitute $u=e^{ix}$:
$$u^2-3iu-1=0;$$
multiply both sides by $4$:
$$4u^2-12iu-4=0;$$
rewrite $4u^2=\left(2u\right)^2$:
$$\left(2u\right)^2-12iu-4=0;$$
add $4+9i^2$ to both sides:
$$\left(2u\right)^2-12iu+9i^2=4+9i^2;$$
rewrite $9i^2=\left(3i\right)^2$:
$$\left(2u\right)^2-12iu+\left(3i\right)^2=4+9i^2;$$
rewrite $\left(2u\right)^2-12iu+\left(3i\right)^2=\left(2u-3i\right)^2$:
$$\left(2u-3i\right)^2=4+9i^2;$$
rewrite $4+9i^2=4-9=-5$:
$$\left(2u-3i\right)^2=-5;$$
take the square roots of both sides:
$$2u-3i=\pm i\sqrt{5};$$
add $3i$ to both sides:
$$2u=3i\pm i\sqrt{5};$$
factor $i$ out:
$$2u=i\left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right);$$
divide both sides by $2$:
$$u=\frac{i}{2}\left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right);$$
substitute back $u=e^{ix}$:
$$e^{ix}=\frac{i}{2}\left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right);$$
rewrite $\frac{i}{2}\left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right)=e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)}$:
$$e^{ix}=e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)};$$
since $1=e^{2i\pi c_1}$ for arbitrary integer $c_1$, multiply the RHS by $e^{2i\pi c_1}$:
$$e^{ix}=e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)}e^{2i\pi c_1};$$
rewrite $e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)}e^{2i\pi c_1}=e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)+2i\pi c_1}$:
$$e^{ix}=e^{\log\left(3i/2\pm i\sqrt{5}/2\right)+2i\pi c_1};$$
eliminate exponentials:
$$ix=\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)+2i\pi c_1;$$
divide both sides by $i$:
$$x=\frac{1}{i}\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)+2\pi c_1;$$
rewrite $1/i=-i$:
$$x=-i\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)+2\pi c_1;$$
rewrite $\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)=\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+\frac{i\pi}{2}$:
$$x=-i\left(\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)+2\pi c_1;$$
expand:
$$x=-i\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\frac{i^2\pi}{2}+2\pi c_1;$$
rewrite $i^2=-1$:
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\log\left(\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2\pi c_1.$$

From the whole set of solutions, the principal inverse sine value is delivered by setting $c_1=0$ and choosing the positive argument of $\log$:
$$\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2}-i\log\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)},$$
where $\log$ is the natural logarithm and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $-2 \leq 2 \sin(x) \leq 2$... So how can this be equal to 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you get $xy = 0$ then you can conclude one or the other is equal to 0. There is UTTERLY NO reason to assume they BOTH have to be 0.

Consider $x = 27; y = 0$ then $xy = 0$ so $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ but $x \ne 0$.  That's *NOT* a contradiction or a problem at all as only *ONE* of the values has to be zero.  They don't both have to 0.

So you got $(2\sin x - 3)(1 + 2\sin x) = 0$. So *ONE* of those terms (not BOTH) is equal to zero.  As $\sin x \le 1$ it's impossible for $\sin x = 3/2$ so $2\sin x - 3 \ne 0$.

That's NOT a problem.  There is no reason on earth you should have assumed it did.

However as it doesn't equal 0, we know the other term *MUST* and we know $\sin x = -1/2$.

Comment: So $(2 \sin x - 3) = -4$ and you have $(2 \sin x - 3)(1 + 2\sin x) = [2(- 1/2) - 3][1 + 2(-1/2)] = [-1 - 3][1 + (-1)] = [-4][0] = 0$.  Not a problem.